# Determinar notas

Tags: pseint

Se tiene la relación de N notas. Elaborar un algoritmo que determinar la nota más baja, la nota más alta, el promedio, el número de aprobados, el número de desaprobados y el número de reprobados. (Aprobado > 11, Desaprobado > 7 y Reprobado < 7).

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?, porque esta no es una comunidad donde te demos cursos bajo demanda

Comment: Por lo menos prueba poner un código.